# Can I install and run a RHEL based lxc on CenOS?

Tags: linux, centos, containers, rhel, lxc

I have been playing with LXC for the past few days and was wondering it is indeed possible and how do I make it work

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [docker](http://www.docker.io/) and I highly recommend it although it's not a production ready version yet.

Here you can find the manual for installing on RHEL which should work for CentOS as well - http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/rhel/.

Good luck.